# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes after resisizing the cursor

Tags: 20.04, crash, cursor

I have tried to change the cursor size on my Focal Fossa. Upon selecting larger cursor size in the Universal Access settings, my Ubuntu froze completely. I rebooted the device. Log-in seemed to process just fine, however after trying to load the screen, it crashed again.

Luckily I managed to solve this by loading the gnome classic version, where I reset the cursor size to default. Upon that I managed to log-in normally.

I have NVIDIA GeForce 940MX, I do have the nvidia-driver-440 installed, this problem persisted also when removing my second screen.

Has anyone experienced this? I would like to know whether there is a solution or it's a bug.